# Intellij-idea 12 Scala support : it consumes almost 300% of my cpu resources

Tags: scala, ide, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, osx-leopard

I recently bought the latest version of Intellij idea (during their 75% off offer) which is really great by the way.

I have a problem though : **the scala support seems to be broken**. I have installed the scala support plugin with the SBT plugin. I have also installed the Play!2 framework support plugin but as soon as I open a scala file from within the IDE, it consumes **almost 300%** of my cpu resources and I can't figure out how to solve this issue.

has anybody experienced this issue on their IDE?

Comment: It can be use a lot of resources while first indexing, but after some time it should calm down. I was testing 12 some time ago, and I don't remember such problems, now, back to Idea 11 cause I missed a End Of The World promo :(

Comment: I waited for about 5 minutes but I still have idea consuming 350~380% of cpu. It is really weird. I can't figure out how to solve this issue.

Comment: I don't know how IntelliJ is configured for JVM resources, but if you can bump up the VM memory resources, perhaps that will help (maybe it is running GC all the time)

Comment: I use intellij 12 with play2 project every day and I don't have such a problem, but I don't have the sbt plugin installed. just scala and play2 support. you can then create the intellij project using idea with-sources=yes in the play console.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but I may find the cause: the memory given to idea is too small. then idea is always doing gc.

what to do: find idea.vmoptions file, add xms to 1500m, and now it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with intelliJ, but rather Play! and Java.

I have idea 12 with play 2.0 plugin. I open the play project in IntelliJ and using the top command I see that java is consuming roughly 3-5% of CPU. If I build the project, that jumps up to 150-300% of CPU and then comes back down after the compiling is done.

Running the same project from the play console, it jumps to about 100% when I first open it, and then if I run `clean` and then `compile`, it jumps to 323% and then comes back down.

You may be able to improve performance by doing compilation from the play console instead of IntelliJ. Just run `clean`, then `compile`, then within IntelliJ you should syncronize the project (alt-ctl-i).

Also, wondering if the version of the jvm has something to do with it. Are you using the sun version or an open source one. IntelliJ recommends using the sun version.

here's my specs:

Idea 123.94, Scala plugin version 0.7.62, Play 2.0 Support 0.2.6,
Play 2.0.4, Scala 2.9.1
java 1.6.0_37-b06, lenovo t410 i7 processor

Comment: I don't see the real advantage of buying an IDE if I have to compile this stuff on the console. Also, I am using a mac with the following java version : java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-384-10M3425)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-384, mixed mode). The scala plugin is 0.7.62 and scala version is 2.9.1.

Comment: @kaffein my point is that the CPU usage on my machine is not caused by intellij but because of javac & play/scala

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem with IntelliJ 12.0.1 on OS X. It constantly consumes 100% CPU (out of 800% for 8 cores) with a codebase containing Java, Groovy and Clojure. Jetbrains tech support told me to download the [unreleased 12.0.2 version](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP).

**Update**: IntelliJ 12.0.4 has the same CPU consumption usage. I've narrowed it down to the Clojure plugin.

Comment: using an unreleased version seems to be dangerous in my opinion but if they say that we should try it then we can try it. We have nothing to lose so ...

Answer (score 0):

in my case I moved objects and classes to different files and that helped( but I haven't had lot of them in single file - just few was enough to get intellij sweat).